# Powerful pictures or plain proceedings?

Tags: polynomials, education

After tutoring someone about polynomial manipulation, my mind went back to this equivalence:
$(a+b)\times (c+d)=ac+ad+bc+bd$
I realized that, while it can be memorized as it is, it has a very simple geometrical interpretation:
[image: rectangle product]
After making a mental note of mentioning this in the future (and feeling a bit guilty for not thinking about it during the session), this other equivalence came to mind:
$(a+b)^3=a^3+3a^2b+3ab^2+b^3$
I realized this too had a similar geometrical interpretation:
[image: cube cube]
So, I had the impulse to dig up old block toys and build the cube, with different sections differently colored.
At this point, I asked myself if bringing the toy cube to the next tutoring session would be a good idea.

I didn't have a similar thought with the first example: the rectangle can be easily drawn with pen and paper, it's an accessible illustration.
The cube, on the other hand, isn't as easy to draw, and not everyone has blocks lying around to mess with.

While I find the cube illustration more elegant and powerful than a plain equivalence to get accustomed to, is there a risk that presenting the cube would create or strengthen a distance between the learner and the subject?
If yes, how can the risk be addressed?
If no, why don't i recall seeing illustrations like these in my textbooks or on the blackboard?

Comment: The first illustration is somewhat standard; the second is not common, because at that level, there is a real risk that the pieces of the larger cube hidden by occlusion will confuse the students. Also, there is the problem that $(a + b)^n$ is straightforward to expand for all $n$, while the illustrations become quickly unhelpful.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I fear my question came out too centered around classroom learning. While I'm curious about how it is and why, I'm more curious about how an individual learns. My last question is tied to the assumption there are no risks, assumption that doesn't have to hold. If there are risks, I'll appreciate answers that describe possible approaches and reasons for choosing them, especially if they address individual learning. For instance, the fear to confuse the average student is not that relevant in front of a single student already confused by what he saw in class.

Comment: Also, there are plenty of cases where a particular aspect is usually addressed from a lot of a different angles, and the general case isn't as much. You necessarily draw functions only for two or three dimensions, you solve second grade polynomials by finding two numbers that summed up give one coefficient and multiplied the other only for particular polynomials with simple coefficients, and so on. I feel a geometrical interpretation could add something, even if not helpful with greater coefficients, but i recognize there could be obstacles, therefore the question.